# background image of the extended html template is not loading in html page, How to solve this problem?

Tags: html, css

I have two html files 'base.html' and 'home.html', the file 'base.html' is having a background image, which is loading properly in 'base.html', I am extending the 'base.html' in 'home.html' , But when I am opening 'home.html' then that background image is not loading in 'home.html' page.

Code from 'base.html' is as :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Medicine information</title>
   <style>
      body  {
      background-image: url("images/med2.jpg");
      background-color: #cccccr;
      background-size:     cover;                  

       }
   </style>
  </head>
       <body>
          {% block content %}
           replace me 
          {% endblock content %}
       <h2> thanks for visiting !!</h2>

     </body>
   </html>
```

code from 'home.html' is :

```
{% extends "htmlfiles/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<H1 style="background-color:DodgerBlue;" > Welcome to our site </H1>

  <HR>

<H2 style="background-color:MediumSeaGreen;">Enter following details </H2>

<form action="{% url 'results_strength_view'  %}" id='b1' method = 'GET'> 
  {%csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type='submit'  value='Get Different Options for Strength' />
</form>

  <HR>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You are using a relative url for your image, if the path directory of your url changes (between base and home), then the image won't work.  Try adding a `/` before  `images` (if the images folder is in the root of your site)

Comment: i tried this also, but it's not working

Comment: Removed the django etc tags, as (until proven otherwise) it's strictly a css issue.

Answer (score -1):

On your settings.py file set up the template path

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")], # you can replace templates
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: i tried {% endblock %} , but it is not solving that problem

Comment: This should be a comment - answers are for answering, not for asking for more details...

Comment: I have got solution for this problem after reading the tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial06/

Comment: And what was the problem?